# Flagging Assistant - tweaks for frequent flaggers

Tags: script, flags

#### About:

Adds several nifty tools/features to assist in tracking your flags:

1. Adds a **shortcut link to the top of every page**.
2. **Summarizes flags by resolution** ("helpful", "declined", etc.)  and provides one-click searching/filtering.
3. **Color codes flag listings.**
4. Tracks changes, to flag counts, between visits to the flag-summary page.
5. Adds **a "Flag Summary" tab** to the user profile -- useful for first flagging on a new site as it takes a while for the "helpful flags" link to become live.
6. For moderators, moves the **user's flagging status up to the top**.
7. For moderators, also summarizes all users' "flag-summary" pages.
8. When following an answer link, **alerts if it has been deleted** (only for < 10K users).

#### Screenshots:

[image: summary table]

---

[image: shortcut link]
[image: missing answer]

#### Download / Install:

[Install the script](https://github.com/BrockA/SE-misc/raw/master/Stack%20Exchange,%20Flagging%20tweaks.user.js) from GitHub:  [**<kbd>Install</kbd>**](https://github.com/BrockA/SE-misc/raw/master/Stack%20Exchange,%20Flagging%20tweaks.user.js)

#### Platform:

Requires the *Tampermonkey*, or the *Violentmonkey*, browser extension (or equivalent).

#### Code:

Find the [source code on GitHub](https://github.com/BrockA/SE-misc/blob/master/Stack%20Exchange,%20Flagging%20tweaks.user.js).

You may also make bug reports, pull-requests, etc. there.

Comment: Can you adjust the icon urls to use https? Since everything is getting migrated to https right now.. It's currently causing a mixed-content warning.

Comment: @Floern, fixed.

Answer (score 3):

<s>[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)</s> : [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The feature #4 is broken for moderators

> Tracks changes, to flag counts, between visits to the flag-summary page.

Moderators can see the flag summaries of all the users, Hence the counts of the individual users are all considered as the flag summaries of that particular moderator. The issue faced here is that I see weird numbers under my flag summary

[image]

I think the fix would be to take the userId also into consideration.

<sub>Fixing this would be of great help as it would help the moderators sneak into the community user's flags</sub>

Comment: @Brock: The HTML structure is the same (on *our* flag summary page, and that of *other users* that we view); but you're storing the flag summary of each /flag-summary/ page we visit as if it was our own summary (hence the crazy numbers).

Comment: @Brock: It should be as simple as extending your "if" check on line #74 to verify the user flag summary being viewed is the currently logged in user; either via "window.location.pathname.startsWith('/users/flag-summary') && StackExchange.options.user.userId == window.location.pathname.match(/flag-summary\/(\d+)/)[1]", or "$('div.user-flag-history div.user-details a[href^="/users"]').prop('href').match(/\/users\/(\d+)/)[1] == StackExchange.options.user.userId". I can submit a PR if need be in the new year.

Comment: Thanks, @Matt.  That's significantly different than the problem report but makes much more sense.  I was interpreting Bhargav Rao's report to mean that a bunch of users flags were displayed on one page.  Anyway, I'll add code to check the page against the logged-in user in a day or two (I'm revamping my computer systems at the moment).  If you beat me to it with a PR, that's good too.

Comment: @BhargavRao, try the new version.  Also, please clean up the comment on the question as it is now redundant.

Comment: @Brock, Looks like we no longer see the box for other users. Thanks. :)

Comment: @BhargavRao, It's been a while but try the recent update (if you are still using this script).

Answer (score 1):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

The stats and the colored table has odd contrast in dark mode:

> [image: the stats contrast]

And the colored table:

> [image: colored flagging table contrast]

It makes some text hard to read.